# How to make a SQL table of formulas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm have a MS SQL database for storing raw data on utility usage (electric, water, and gas), which I have implemented to compile data from four disparate automated collection systems.  The ultimate goal is to generate invoices from this data.

Different customers have one of a dozen different rate structures, which all may-or-may-not use a non-linear function to calculate cost per usage based on peak demand and total usage.

It is not unheard of for a particular customer to change from one rate structure to another, or for the rate calculation for a particular rate class to change from year to year, so I would like to put these formulas into new tables within my database where they can be easily referenced and modified.

Ideally, I would want to run one of these dynamic functions as part of a query without relying on the front-end having to do them, but I have no idea how that would work.

By request, an example formula of the type I am talking about:

All current customer with Electricity Rate Structure A pay $0.005/kW-hr for the first 2,000 kW-hr consumed, $0.004/kW-hr for 2,000-15,000 kW-hr, and $0.003/kW-hr for all consumption above 15,000kW-hr.  Additionally, any customer who has higher than 50kW demand will be subject to a $0.002/kW-hr surcharge on all consumption.  The values for these coefficients, thresholds, the number of thresholds, and whether or not the customer even gets charged for peak demand can and do change from year to year and from rate structure to rate structure.

The formula for this (if I was programming it) would be:

```
min(sum(usage),2000)*.005+min(min(sum(usage)-2000,0),15000)*.004 + min(sum(usage)-15000,0)*.002 + (max(usage)>50)*sum(usage)*.002
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the different types of rate structures?

Comment: Seems to me you may want to create user-defined functions in SQL Server to accomplish this instead of storing the functions as values in a table. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx

Comment: This is more of a whiteboard question, which is more appropriate for [programmers.se]. From experience, I'd have a rate calculation table related to the customer. From the value in that table, I'd know what rate structure to use in code.  I definitely would not attempt to calculate rates in sql.  I would record the calculated result as a bill record.

Comment: another suggestion: create a table with computed columns for each of the formulas, then use a customer_rate_structure table to determine which one is valid for an individual customer, then pull that value using a CASE expression.

Comment: @will At present, there doesn't appear to be enough detail in the question to make it answerable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey meh, I think it's pretty clear he isn't sure about the design for this, and it's not too hard to suggest good designs for such a system.  But, yeah, you need to respect the quality standards of the SE site you post to (if that isn't obvious, which it should be).

Comment: How does one move a question?

Comment: The sample formula you provided can actually be stored in a table with different rates per amounts of usages on different schedule.  Would it be a true statement that the formula need rate configuration, and not an entirely new formula?

Comment: The form of the formula I gave is typical, but the number of terms in it are variable.  The particular example I gave could be stored in a table format, but if next year, the power company revises the formula so that e.g. 2000-5000 kW-hr are charged at a different rate than 5000-10000kW-hr, but only for certain customers, that throws my table for a loop.

Comment: @Frank - That doesn't really break the idea of the table.  You just need to define the schedule

Comment: @BradD - How do you mean "define the schedule"?  If that is a dbm concept I am not familiar with it.